# Is there any way to print?

Tags: apps, printer

I have a wireless printer. Is there any way I can spool something to the printer from my Windows phone?

Occasionally, I'd like to print a document, a web page, or maybe a picture right from my phone. But I have to either move it from my phone to my PC to do it, or I have to copy it to OneDrive first and print it from there. Even the latter can't be done from my phone because Internet Explorer on the phone does not have a print function.

Maybe there is an App to do this that I don't know of. I did read about an [App called RoboPrint](http://www.windowscentral.com/roboprint-app-spotlight-updated) that appeared to do exactly what I wanted. But the website for the product seems to have vanished and the App is not in the Windows store, nor does there appear to be any other Apps for printing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several printer apps that work with various print setups - Brother printers, HP, or Google Cloud print. You can search for apps at http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/search?q=print

edit: I notice you say there don't seem to be any apps. If you are not from the US, try changing your phone to the US marketplace following these instructions: http://www.symbianmobiletutorial.com/2013/05/how-to-change-the-windows-phone-marketplace-region.html

Answer (score 0):

What is it you'd like to print? A PDF or Excel File? Pictures? Screenshots. In theory it would be possible to create an application that can handle printing to a network attached printer. A simpler alternative would be to create a "host" application that runs on a computer that the Windows Phone app can talk to. In that regard, you can send documents to the host and it would be responsible for printing.

Taken a step further, you can make a cloud service that allows you to send documents for printing to an email address. Those documents would then be sent to your printer and ready for you to pick up when you get home.

Comment: Just realized that without even looking at your link, I described RoboPrint to a T.