# Printing PDF file via Google CloudPrint

Tags: lumia, pdf, printer

What is the procedure, how to print PDF to [CloudPrint](https://www.google.com/cloudprint/#printers) from windows phone?

Comment: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1969/is-there-any-way-to-print/1980 doesn't describe how to do it.

Comment: Which app are you using?

Comment: @RowlandShaw http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/pdf-reader/8f6154d6-1b70-431a-a579-b6a43477e837

Comment: That app makes no claim to support printing. You need to use a different app

Answer (score 1):

### Part1 (adding non cloud aware printer to list of google printers)

This can be done either by [`Chrome browser`](https://support.google.com/cloudprint/answer/1686197?rd=1) or [`Cloud Print Service`](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/cloudprintservice)

### Part2

Installing one of the following apps on your phone and linking them to your google account.

[image: WinPhonePrint8.1]
[WinPhonePrint8.1](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/winphoneprint8-1/eeb7d477-d22c-4b0a-afb4-240f2cf45591)

[image: Print Now]
[Print Now](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/print-now/43770b7b-daad-466d-926b-0e0df6ddbdb1)

[image: KumoPrint]
[KumoPrint](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/kumoprint/fccd095d-d491-4a6d-9c30-0f3ec0576576)